# Connect to RDS in Python using pymysql using VPC Peering

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

I am trying to connect to a RDS Instance from a Python runtime Lambda Function.

Both the RDS and the Lambda are in a different VPC. I have connected both VPC's using `VPC Peering` and have confirmed that the peering is successful using EC2 instances.

My VPC A is on the `CIDR 172.31.0.0/16`,
VPC B is on the `CIDR 10.1.0.0/16`.

The SG's are configured using CIDR's and so are the routes.

The Route Table has the entries as such

VPC A route table:

**Destination** `10.1.0.0/16`
**Target** `pcx-xxxxxxx`

VPC B route table:

**Destination** `172.31.0.0/16`
**Target** `pcx-xxxxxxx`

**Destination** `10.2.0.0/16`
**Target** `pcx-1234567`

SG for VPC A

```
Inbound

Type - MYSQL/ Aurora
Protocol - TCP
Port - 3306
Source - 10.1.0.0/16
```

SG for VPC B

```
Outbound

Type - All traffic
Protocol - All
Port - All
Destination - 172.31.0.0/16
```

VPC B is also using VPC peering with a different VPC in a different region, to access a different service other than RDS.
Inside a Lambda I can access that service using `boto3`
When I try to connect to the RDS using `pymysql`, the `pymysql.connect` timeout. I tried to create a VPC endpoint interface for the RDS and use that as the endpoint that I connect to but that doesn't work either.

If I were to give internet access to the lambda then I can access the RDS instance but I don't want to use that solution.

Comment: Please edit your Question and include the configuration of the Outbound rules on the Lambda' security group, and also the Inbound rules on the RDS database security group.

Comment: I presume that RDS is in VPC A and the Lambda function is in VPC B? Are the security groups you have shown associated with the RDS database / the Lambda function? You could temporarily try opening them to `0.0.0.0/0` just to be sure that the Security Groups are not the cause of the problem.

Comment: How is the Lambda function referring to the RDS instance? Is it using a DNS name? Is the RDS database set to `Publicly accessible = Yes`?

Comment: I am using the Endpoint that you get from the RDS console. 
Additionally, I tried to telnet to the endpoint in the EC2 instance and it worked.

Comment: The RDS is publicly accessible, and I also tried opening them to 0.0.0.0/0, but it still results in a timeout.

Comment: Then that's your problem... If the RDS is publicly accessible, its IP address resolves to a **public IP address**. This is not routable within the VPC Peering you have described. Is there a reason why you have set it to Publicly Accessible? Is the RDS database in a public subnet or a private subnet?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks, Thats what it was! I made the RDS not publicly accessible and the connection was working. If you don’t mind can you post an answer, I don’t want to post an answer and take your credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you have `Publicly Accessible = Yes`.

From [Working with a DB instance in a VPC - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html):

> When you launch a DB instance inside a VPC, the DB instance has a private IP address for traffic inside the VPC. This private IP address isn't publicly accessible. You can use the Public access option to designate whether the DB instance also has a public IP address in addition to the private IP address. If the DB instance is designated as **publicly accessible**, its DNS endpoint resolves to the private IP address from within the VPC. **It resolves to the public IP address from outside of the VPC.**

This means that the Lambda function (in VPC B) will resolve the RDS DNS name to a public IP address, which is not routable via the VPC Peering connection.

You can either set `Publicly acccessible = No` (which is safer), or connect via the Internet, or somehow resolve the RDS DNS name to a private IP address use it for the connection. (Not sure how you would do this from VPC B.)